# What is a sparse subset?

Tags: definition

In a [work about fully homomorphic encryption](http://crypto.stanford.edu/craig/craig-thesis.pdf) I found usage of the expression: "sparse subset", as in:

> Our hint will consist of a set of vectors that has a (secret) sparse
>   subset of vectors whose sum is **v**$_J^{sk^*}$

How exactly is such sparseness defined in general? Or it is a notion created by Craig Gentry and it just means that there are *not that many* vectors and that distances between them are *fairly big*?

Comment: "Sparse" is a standard term; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what does that mean in terms of subsets of vectors then?

Comment: I think it means it's a small subset of vectors (relative to the size of the set of vectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparse here means the following: $S\subseteq T$ (where $T$ is finite, and has size $n=|T|$ for $n$ considered as going to infinity) is *sparse* if $\frac{|S|}{|T|} = o(1)$. See e.g. an example on the last line of p.16.